# ASP.NET HTTPS redirect & HSTS headers

Tags: asp.net, azure, https, web-config, hsts

We have an ASP.NET site hosted in Azure.

Previously we implemented the following Rewrite rule to force HTTPS:

```
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$|^post$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

We are now introducing HSTS via the following rule (from [this guide](https://tomssl.com/2016/06/30/how-to-fix-the-http-response-headers-on-azure-web-apps-to-get-an-a-plus-on-securityheaders-io/)):

```
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security only when using HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
```

Do we need both rules or can we remove the HTTPS rule and only have the HSTS one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need both.

HSTS should only be applied to secure requests per the spec. It would not make sense to apply it to insecure requests since a man-in-the-middle could just strip the header.

If a request comes in with HTTP, you must first redirect them to HTTPS. Then return the HSTS header in the response.

Quote from spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-7.2

> An HSTS Host MUST NOT include the STS header field in HTTP responses
> conveyed over non-secure transport.